# Lambda function with for loop and if-else statement

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this

```
index       Posts                    clean_text
  0     Hi I am fine.              [Hi, I, am, fine]
  1     You are a piece of shit.   [You, are, a, piece, of, shit]
.
.
.
```

I have a list named `corpus` that has 3000 foul words.

I want to go through the column `clean_text` and add a new row `result` to the `df` by check a condition for all the rows. The condition is:
if any one of the words of the list in any row of the column `clean_text` is present in the `corpus`, the column `result` will have the string `Irrelevant`, otherwise `Relevant`.

Example: if any word of the list `[Hi, I, am, fine]` is present in the `corpus`, the column `result` will have `Irrelevant`, otherwise `relevant`. Since, this list dose not have any foul words, the output should be `relevant`.

The desired output is :

```
index       Posts                    clean_text                       result
  0     Hi I am fine.              [Hi, I, am, fine]                  Relevant
  1     You are a piece of shit.   [You, are, a, piece, of, shit]     Irrelevant
.
.
.
```

I want to do this using lambda function. I have done this so far-

`df['result'] = df['clean_text'].map(lambda x: ["Relevant" for w in x if w not in corpus])`
Firstly, I am unable to write the `else` part here and secondly it is showing an undesirable output like below.

```
index       Posts                    clean_text                       result
  0     Hi I am fine.              [Hi, I, am, fine]                  [Relevant, Relevant, Relevant, Relevant]
  1     You are a piece of shit.   [You, are, a, piece, of, shit]     [Relevant, Relevant, Relevant,...]
.
.
.
```

I also tried writing a ``for``` loop like this but it takes a lot of time:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for word in df.loc[i]['clean_text']:
      if word in corpus:
        df['result'] = "Irrelevant"
        #break
      else:
        #continue
        df['result'] = "Relevant"
```

Kindly help me to get the desired output using lambda function.

Comment: why does it have to be a lambda expression? Why not a regular function defintion?

Comment: Probably the biggest problem is that you are using a *list* for corpus. You should use a `set`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , how will set help ?

Comment: Because membership testing in a `set` is constant time, whereas in a  list it's linear time.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i can change that to set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `corpus = set(corpus)`.

Then you can use something like

```
df['clean_text'].map(lambda l: "Relevant" if any(x in corpus for x in l) else "Irrelevant")
```

Note, the fact that you are using a `lambda` is really not relevant. You could have done something like:

```
def search_corpus(tokens):
    if any(token in corpus for token in tokens):
        return "Relevant"
    return "Irrelevant"
```

And do:

```
df['clean_text'].map(search_corpus)
```

And this won't affect performance. `lambda` expressions don't create anything special, and you *never* have to use one.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Also, is there a way by which I can check which words are matchng from the corpus and add those in a separate column.

Comment: @dipanjana why not `map(lambda l: [x for x in l if x in corpus])`